# Module not being set up properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

New-ish to python, but I though I had everything set up right. When I run `python -m unittest test.unit.test_oyez_case`, I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_oyez_case'`

Sorry this is a frequent question, none of the responses were helpful to me

Here's my file structure:

```
├── README.md
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── integration
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── mocks
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── __init__.pyc
        │   ├── responses.py
        │   └── responses.pyc
        ├── test_oyez_case.py
        └── test_oyez_case.pyc
```

Here's `test/unit/test_oyez_case.py`:

```
import json
import unittest

import responses

from mocks import responses as api_responses
from puppy_scotus.oyez_case import OyezCase

class TestOyezCase(unittest.TestCase):
    . . .

if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run using a commandline like `python test_oyez_case.py` ?

Comment: It works now, using this suggestion I realized that one of the other imports was incorrect, and I did not know that would stop the test_oyez_case module from failing. If post this as an answer I'll mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run it using a commandline like `python test_oyez_case.py`. It could be that one of your other imports is incorrect. ;-)